# regex match .net lessthan "<" (name)W7

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

I'm trying to match what I would think would be a very simple regex in vb.net though I haven't really used them very much, and there should be multiple occurrences in the text file i'm reading into a string. the match I'm using is

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, "<[A-B]+W7", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

have also tried

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, "<[\w]+W7", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

What I need is something that would match a name for something that always starts with `<`, followed by a name ending in `W7`. For example `<TESTW7`. I then need to grab all occurrences from the match.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Edit

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, "\<(\w+)W7", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The above line matches a single case, but I'm trying to match multiple. for example
`<BEARW7>`
`<<<ROOMW7>`
`<<VIVALDIW7>`
`<< AMESW7>`

I need to save BEARW7, ROOMW7, VIVALDIW7, and AMESW7 into an array or list, but can't seem to match past "BEARW7", is there some way to make it match multiple cases like with boost's regex?

Comment: Have you tried debuggex.com to look at what your regex does and does not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the first regex `<[A-B]+W7` the problem is that you're only matching strings where the `(name)` part contains, at least one character or more (because of +) in the range A-B, that is, A or B.

As I can think because of the second regex, you want a `(name)` to contain any character (letter and numbers), so, as you're using the `IgnoreCase` option you should use instead the `[0-9A-Z]` range, and you will match at least, one or more letter/digit from A-Z and from 0-9 in lower or uppercase.

So you should use `<[0-9A-Z]+W7`.

- In the second regex `<[\w]+W7` I think that there isn't any problem as you're matching the type of string that you are stating.

I haven't worked with Regular Expressions in Visual Basic.NET, and as @AlanMoore says, it doesn't create any conflict with the special syntax for regex, so I don't know what could be wrong. You can try to escape it in order to stay sure, but it's not needed.

And maybe there is some strange conflict with the part of the `W7` (but I don't think so) so you can put them between parenthesis in order to avoid possible conflicts.

So you should use `<[0-9A-Z]+(W7)` or `<[\w]+(W7)`.

If it's the case (i don't know exactly by your example) that you don't want to match digits, you mustn't use the second regex, and you have to trim digits from the first regex.

So you should use `<[A-Z]+(W7)`

> Note that without the `IgnoreCase` option, the second regular expression will continue working as it matches any letter (upper or lowercase), but the first one only matches uppercase letters.

I recommend you http://www.regexr.com/ in order to try regular expressions before using them in a program. It has an excellent cheatsheet too.

Comment: Angle brackets never need to be escaped.  They are used in some of the special group constructs, but those always start with `(?`.  It's impossible to use `<` or `>` as a metacharacter by accident.  (The only exception I know of is pre-2012 versions of Visual Studio, but it uses the .NET flavor now.)

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you for the response, I have edited the response so I don't confuse anyone.

Comment: I am only looking for letters, A-B or a-b, but i'm using regex.options ignore case. The names are all actual names, some of composers, some of islands, etc. but as far as I know all contain only letters for the "name" part, and all are followed by "w7", 

EDIT after reading Alan's comment: this is visual studio 2010. So does that mean it needs to be escaped?

Comment: @user3361936 No, you haven’t read the answer properly. The issue is that you’re using `A-B` instead of `A-Z`. If you want more than one match, use `Matches` instead of `Match`.

Comment: Ah wow I can't believe I missed that. Okay, I'll try Matches. Thank you